# sudo: source: command not found

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo

I've been updating some of the default profile for bash, and saw from the tutorials I was following that I could reload the new profile with the new environment settings by using:

```
source /etc/bash.bashrc
```

The only thing is - the new environment variables were only available to my current user - and were ignored when I used sudo. They only became available to sudo when I closed my terminal session and rejoined.

When I try to use:

```
sudo source /etc/bash.bashrc
```

I get the error:

```
sudo: source: command not found
```

Is there a simple way to load in the new bash profile settings for sudo without having to close the terminal and restart?

--
Initially, I was using some installer scripts which referenced the variables. I found that while they could access the variables when I called the scripts directly (although, this would cause a later problem with creating directories as I needed to be root), calling the install scripts using sudo wouldn't.

I proved this by testing with these simple commands:

```
echo $ENV_VARIABLE
sudo echo $ENV_VARIABLE
```

The first would output the variable's value, but the second wouldn't output anything.

Comment: How did you try to use the variables from sudo ? Please note that if you use "sudo command $variable" it will replace the variable from your shell, not from sudo's environment.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

The problem is that `source` is a bash build-in command (not a program - like `ls` or `grep`). I think one approach is to login as root and then execute the source command.

```
sudo -s
source /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Comment: You're right that the problem is that `source` is a shell builtin. `sudo su` is a kind of weird way to say it -- better to just say `sudo -s` which is sudo's own way of saying "start a shell as this user."  Your one-line version won't work because each of the commands in it is run by the main user's shell in a separate subprocess.

Comment: Right. Plus BASH reads /etc/bashrc at login time. So you may as well use 'su' with -, -l, or --login switch in order to get the environment of that user: 'sudo su -' to become root or 'su - $username' to become another user.

Comment: The "one line" example won't work because `su` starts a new shell and "source" is run only after it terminates. The first example only works if the second line used *inside* the root shell.

Comment: `sudo -s` is no better than `sudo su`. It won't have any effect either way.

Comment: `sudo -s` has a similar effect of starting a shell, but to me it seems inelegant to stack two "become another user" commands when one would do.

Answer (score 18):

The problem is not that `source` is a shell builtin command. *The fact that it is* is what's actually throwing you the `command not found` error, but it doesn't mean it would work if it were.

The actual problem is how environment variables work. And they work like this:
every time a new process is started, if nothing happens, it inherits the environment of its parent. Due to this, using a subshell (e.g. typing `bash` inside a bash instance) and looking at the output of `env` should give similar results than its parent.

However, due to how `sudo` works (as stated in its manpage), sudo tries to strip the environment of the user and create a "default" environment for the supplanting user, so that the command run is run *as if* the user who invoked it had been the calling user (which is the expected behaviour), and thus running nautilus as `sudo nautilus` should open a folder at the `/root` folder, and not `/home/yourusername`.

So:

Doing something like `sudo source script.sh` and then `sudo command`, even if it worked, it wouldn't be successful at setting any variable to the later `sudo command`.

In order to pass environment variables, you can either tell sudo to preserve the environment (via the `-E` switch; and having appropriate permissions in your sudoers file) and/or setting it for the command as `sudo VAR1=VALUE1 VAR2=VALUE2 command`.

Answer (score 13):

Using bash [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) you can do:

```
source <(sudo cat /etc/bash.bashrc)
```

Comment: How would this help starting a root shell with the new settings, which is what OP is looking to do?

Comment: The OP was actually asking how to "... reload the new profile ..." from a shell which needs to use `sudo` to access the profile. The above provides a means to import the profile whilst avoiding the `sudo: source: command not found` issue mentioned.

Comment: "The only thing is - the new environment variables were only available to my current user - and were ignored when I used sudo."

Comment: This is my favorite answer. It works very well.

Comment: Worked for me. Great solution. I needed to source a `.bash_profile` *as* another user, without being able to `su` to that user directly. The following worked: `source <(sudo -u theuser cat /home/theuser/.bash_profile)`. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As [Marcos says](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20953/sudo-source-command-not-found/20955#20955), your main problem here is that `source` is a shell builtin command that affects only the shell process in which it's run.

The easy solution is to just start a new shell as root, and bash will automatically read `/etc/bash.bashrc` when it starts.  That's as simple as just saying

```
sudo bash
```

Answer (score 2):

Closing and reopening the terminal should not change things.  By default, sudo strips the environment.  To disable that, add -E to sudo.

Answer (score 2):

The error happens because the binary you are trying to call from command line is only part of the current user's PATH variable, but not a part of  root user's PATH.

You can verify this by locating the path of the binary you are trying to access. In my case I was trying to call "bettercap-ng". So I ran,

```
$ which bettercap-ng
/home/user/work/bin/bettercap`
```

I checked whether this location is part of my root user's PATH.

```
$ sudo env | grep ^PATH
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
```

So sudo cannot find the binary that I am trying to call from commandline. Hence returns the error command not found.

You can direct sudo to use the current user's PATH when calling a binary like below.

```
sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" [command] [arguments]
```

In fact, one can make an alias out of it:

```
alias mysudo='sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH"'
```

It's also possible to name the alias itself sudo, replacing the original sudo.

Answer (score 2):

Some UNIX shell does not support `source`. instead, they support `.` So try this

```
. /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Hope it works

Comment: That won't work here. It's still a shell builtin, and even if it did work it'd set up an environment that'd immediately vanish as the command finished.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `source` is a built in command, not a program. I wrote a bash script to force sudo on built in commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

function forceSudo()
{
    command="${@}"
    file="${@: -1}"
    if ! $command 2>/dev/null
    then
        permission=$(stat -c '%a' $file)
        sudo chmod o+rx $file
        result=$command 2>/dev/null
        sudo chmod $permission $file
        if ! $result
        then
            echo $result
        fi
    fi
}
```

Save the file as `forceSudo` and save it in your scripts location, possibly `~/.local/bin`. To avoid having to source the file before using the function, add `alias forceSudo='unalias forceSudo && . forceSudo && forceSudo "$@"'` to `~/.bashrc`.

Now you can use `forceSudo source /etc/bash.bashrc`.