# source command not found

Tags: source

I installed python environment and everything related to that being a user xxx and in group nginx. When I try to activate the environment using the `source /path/to/activate` being user xxx I can do it but when I log in as user yyy who is in the group nginx  and try to use the command -`source /path/to/activate` I am getting this error message:

```
source: command not found.
```

I have looked at [sudo: source: command not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20953/sudo-source-command-not-found), but that doesn't help.

Comment: What's in you `$PATH`variable ?

Comment: @EricLeschinski It _does_ matter what the user has tried. Saad should have clarified why it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I finally found a solution to this problem. When I create a new user that new user will have less functionality in command line. He wont be able to use UP arrow keys or copy and paste from the shell or commands like source and autocomplete. The reason for this is that the new user will be using default shell /bin/sh and all these functionality exists in /bin/bash. So one way to get around this is just change the shell you are using by typing the name of the shell.

```
$ bash
```

and it will change to bash shell and prompt will change as well by displaying the user and local host as well as the current directory like this.

```
user@localhost$
```